# Kendo UI Grid - edit popup - cancel - Jquery "too much recursion" error

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I have a huge viewModel (3300 lines) so its probably pointless to paste all the code here and will paste depending on help I get in narrowing the area that could be causing this issue.

The viewModel was written by some other developer and serves as a reusable business function that is accessed by many modules of the application. I am doing a "change" in the model to conform to new functionalities. But I am facing this issue.

There are 3 grids in the viewModel. Each is displayed based on which of the 7 modules is calling this viewModel. Each of the grid is almost the same in every logic (no idea why made into three different - and have no time to find out why and merge them all). And this issue is occurring in only 1 of them. When a record is opened in the popup edit mode and cancel button is pressed, the browser goes in to not responding state for couple of seconds and then the error "too much recursion" is seen in the debugger.

I need to know what can be the root cause to this, what part of the code do I need to show here to find this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is coming due to references of libraries, but I am not sure.

Anyway you can cross check your code with below link:

[Reference Guide](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/custom#combined-scripts)

It says:

> Important: kendo.all.min.js is available in the Kendo UI Professional,
>   Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC, Telerik UI for JSP and Telerik UI for PHP
>   bundles. The contents of kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js are not included in
>   kendo.all.min.js - you need to include kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js in
>   addition to kendo.all.min.js or use the custom download builder tool.

Then

> Important: Only one of the combined JavaScript files can be included
>   at a time, because they include the Kendo UI framework. If widgets
>   from different Kendo UI suites will be used simultaneously, you should
>   use kendo.all.min.js or build a custom script.

and last but not least

> Registering duplicate scripts may cause Javascript errors and unexpected behavior.

Hope this will help you and solve your problem. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: This seems promising, will see if this helps

Comment: Ok used Chrome debugger, what I found it that this particular exception is repeatedly thrown on that page after cancelling the edit popup window: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element':..................

Comment: Is that a kendo ui related bug? I assume you are trying to access element by wrong selector.

Comment: found the problem. Some how the exception on cancel event of this grid stopped coming when databound of another grid got commented out :/ no idea how that one is related to this... since it is someone else's code I really need to drill down and see... thanks for the help

Comment: Glad you found root cause